# Json Object in ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, json

response object like

```
$scope.list= [
Object {
  cid=74,
  date="2016-08-25T00:00:00.000+0530",
  optkey="key",
  optvalue="{
    value:{
      'name':test,
      'gender':male
    }
  }"
},
Object {
 cid=75,
 date="2016-08-25T00:00:00.000+0530",
 optkey="key",
 optvalue="{
   value:{
     'name':test2,
     'gender':female
   }
 }"
}},
Object {
  cid=77,
  date="2016-08-26T00:00:00.000+0530",
  optkey="key",
  optvalue="{
    value:{
      'name':test1,
      'gender':female
    }
  }"
}]
```

and in html page used ng-repeat

```
<div ng-repeat="item in list">
  {{item.date}} -- works fine
</div>
```

here how to display json value in object  optvalue, done some code like.

```
<div ng-repeat="item in list">
  {{item.optvalue.value}} -- but it is undefined
</div>
```

but it is not working can any one give hint for this

Comment: Response is not in a json format. First you correct it. Check the url http://www.json.org/

Comment: Did you check my answer? If it helped you then mark it.

Answer (score 0):

Just because your `optvalue` is a String but not a object. It should be :

```
optvalue = {
    value:{
      'name':test1,
      'gender':female
    }
}
```

In JSON, an object should **NOT** be in the parenthese.

Comment: the json format is fetching from database,in database column type is string,so optvalue getting as string

Comment: @Basavaraj, so you should do some transformation of `optvalue` in your backend, or do the same thing in your angular controller in frontend, before sending it to the template.

Answer (score 0):

Try this working example, please check the object created.

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {

$scope.list= 
  [
    { 
       cid:74, date:"2016-08-25T00:00:00.000+0530",  optkey:"key",  optvalue:{value:{'name':'test','gender':'male'}}
    },
    {  
      cid:75, date:"2016-08-25T00:00:00.000+0530",  optkey:"key",  optvalue:{value:{'name':'test','gender':'male'}}
    },
    { 
      cid:76, date:"2016-08-25T00:00:00.000+0530",  optkey:"key",  optvalue:{value:{'name':'test','gender':'male'}}
    }
  ] 

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
<div ng-repeat="item in list">
  {{item.optvalue.value.name}}
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The `response` JSON is not valid **:**

1. Strings should be wrapped in double quotes.
2. Expecting colon, not = in key value pairs.
3. Invalid characters found.
4. Invalid number.

**Issue Capture :**

[image]

**Valid JSON :**

```
[
  {
    "cid": 74,
    "date": "2016-08-25T00:00:00.000+0530",
    "optkey": "key",
    "optvalue": {
      "value": {
        "name": "test",
        "gender": "male"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "cid": 75,
    "date": "2016-08-25T00:00:00.000+0530",
    "optkey": "key",
    "optvalue": {
      "value": {
        "name": "test2",
        "gender": "female"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "cid": 77,
    "date": "2016-08-26T00:00:00.000+0530",
    "optkey": "key",
    "optvalue": {
      "value": {
        "name": "test1",
        "gender": "female"
      }
    }
  }
]
```

In your case  `{{item.optvalue.value}}` is giving `undefined` because `optvalue` is a string not an object.So, it should be an `object`.

```
"optvalue": {
          "value": {
            "name": "test1",
            "gender": "female"
          }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

thanks for your answers,i have resolved it using--

```
angular.toJson and angular.fromJson
```

while send to server used

```
angular.toJson(stringOfJson)
```

and when got the response object the using

```
angular.fromJson(value)
```

and set to object field,it is working fine.

Answer (score -1):

you need to change your code to this

```
<div ng-repeat="item in list">
 {{item.optvalue.value.name}} 
</div>
```

Comment: As Basavaraj says, `item.optvalue.value` is undefined.